# How do I restrict acces to all my APIs to one user role and only allow other on a few of them in JAX-RS?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, jakarta-ee-security-api

This is my Jersey Application Config:

```
@ApplicationPath("/ui/v1.0")
@RolesAllowed("admin")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        System.out.println("!!!!!! Insights v10 UI starts !!!!!....");
        packages("com.test.app.ws.v10.ui");
        register(SecurityFilter.class);
        register(AuthenticationExceptionMapper.class);
        register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
    }
}
```

My authentication and authorization are working properly. I want all my APIs to have restricted access for one role only and only a few exceptions for other role types. Writing `@RolesAllowed("admin")` in all my web services is quite a tedious task as there are hundreds of them.

Is there a way to specify `@RolesAllowed("admin")` in such a way that all the web services take this by default and I can use `@PermitAll` only on the few exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Override the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` and add a default role to every endpoint at the end of the `configure` method if there are no other role based annotations for that endpoint.

```
@Override
public void configure(final ResourceInfo resourceInfo, final FeatureContext configuration) {
    final AnnotatedMethod am = new AnnotatedMethod(resourceInfo.getResourceMethod());

    // DenyAll on the method take precedence over RolesAllowed and PermitAll
    if (am.isAnnotationPresent(DenyAll.class)) {
        configuration.register(new RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.RolesAllowedRequestFilter());
        return;
    }

    // RolesAllowed on the method takes precedence over PermitAll
    RolesAllowed ra = am.getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
    if (ra != null) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ra.value()));
        configuration.register(new RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.RolesAllowedRequestFilter(ra.value()));
        return;
    }

    // PermitAll takes precedence over RolesAllowed on the class
    if (am.isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class)) {
        // Do nothing.
        return;
    }

    // DenyAll can't be attached to classes

    // RolesAllowed on the class takes precedence over PermitAll
    ra = resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
    if (ra != null) {
        configuration.register(new RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.RolesAllowedRequestFilter(ra.value()));
    }

    // If no other role is assigned, assign a default role "admin"
    if (!am.isAnnotationPresent(DenyAll.class) && !am.isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class)
            && !am.isAnnotationPresent(RolesAllowed.class)) {
        configuration.register(new RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.RolesAllowedRequestFilter(new String[] {"admin"}));
    }
}
```